# cakephp back end an ionic application

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, ionic2

i use cakephp in back end and when i try to login in my application ionic Knowing when i use method POST i get : Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500 in console of my browser.

but when i use method GET all things are working but i noticed when i check data requeste i found that array is void nothing inside.
i don't know why when i use post is not working where is problem 
thanks.

**service.js**

```
            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post(
                link,
                {"data.User.password": pw, "data.User.username": email},
                config
            ).then(
                function(response) {
                    //console.info(response);
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse) {
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );

            return promise;
        }
    }
})
```

**usercontroller.php**

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->set(array(
            'message' => array(
                'text' => __('You are logged in!'),
                'type' => 'error',
                'status' => 200,
                'success' => 1
            ),
            '_serialize' => array('message')
        ));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //debug($this->request->data);
        //die;
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            //debug($this->Session->read('Auth.User'));
            //die;
            //return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());

            //debug('if**********************************');
            //die;

            $this->set(array(
                'user' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User'),
                '_serialize' => array('user')
            ));
        } else {
            //debug('else *************************');
            //die;
            $array_data = array_keys($this->request->data);
            $this->set(array(
                'message' => array(
                    'text' => __('Invalid username or password, try again'),
                    'type' => 'error',
                    'status' => 200,
                    'success' => 0,
                    'data_0' => $this->request->data
                    //'data_1'=>$_GET['password'] 
                ),
                '_serialize' => array('message')
            ));
            // $this->response->statusCode(401);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, when posting code, please format it in a properly readable manner, arbitrarily indented code will distract people, and decrease your chances of receiving an answer. That being said, if you receive a 500 response, then an error happened on the server side, hence you should investigate that - start by checking the logs.

Comment: what you meaning by post requet code??

Comment: I got confused with all the headers you have set access-control-* are all server side headers not sent by client

Comment: `{"data.User.password": pw, "data.User.username": email}` also not sure how you are reading these keys in server side...

Comment: The various CORS and other header you have in `config` var are supposed to be set on server side not client.

Comment: yuh i also set on server but stil same problem but when execut this command :chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security .          the probelm is solved